# Getting IllegalArgumentException while trying to submit a form in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting IllegalArgumentException while trying to submit a form in JSP. I am trying to route this request to a spring mvc controller. Though the message is pretty clear, I do not understand what needs to be changed.
Here is the exception trace-

`Apr 25, 2017 9:29:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [EWeb] in context with path [/EWeb] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: argument type mismatch
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.test.pm.crequest.web.NewRequestController]
Method [protected void com.test.pm.crequest.web.NewRequestController.onSubmitAction(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.Object,org.springframework.validation.BindException) throws java.lang.Exception]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@102ab327]
[1] [type=org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@4e25c43b]
[2] [type=java.lang.Object] [value=java.lang.Object@9ebd244]
[3] [type=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] [value=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors]
] with root cause`

Comment: Can you show your controller `onSubmitAction` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the parameters in the onSubmitMethod to:

```
protected String onSubmitAction(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute CRequestForm command, BindingResult errors)
        throws Exception {
```

and the issue was resolved.